# How to open a project directory in a new MacVim window with NERDTree

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

If I want to open, say, a Rails app in MacVim with NERDTree, I simply do

`$ mvim .`

from that directory. A new window open with the NERDTree navigator on the left and a buffer on the right.

Now let's say I want to do the same thing, but I already have a MacVim window open. From that window, I want to do exactly what I did above, but without needing to go back to the command line.

I do Cmd-N to open a new window, then I type: `:e ~/path/to/new/project`. But the NERDTree navigator I get here doesn't work correctly. It's as if it's not aware of the buffer to its right. It doesn't expand or collapse directories and pressing enter on any of the files will open it in the same window as the navigator.

I'm new to all this, so hopefully my terminology and description make some sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `mvim` script bundled with MacVim is in your `$PATH` you can simply do:

```
:!mvim ~/path/to/new/project
```

Answer (score 1):

From wherever you are, you can issue `:NERDTree ~/path/to/new/project` and NERDTree will open up with ~/path/to/new/project as the root. I tried it out and it behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks! This was not exactly what I was looking for, but learning it was very helpful!